# When I do "git pull origin master --rebase" from a feature branch, I receive outdated incoming code

Tags: git, github, version-control, rebase, git-pull

Not sure if it's something I did incorrectly that leads to this behavior...

I have a master branch and a feature branch assumably named "feature".

Below are the operations that I've done:

1. Made some changes on the feature branch
2. Run "git pull origin master --rebase" on the feature branch to get changes from my teammates
3. Pushed the changes to remote feature branch with "git push origin feature"
4. Realized I need to fix something, so I made some changes
5. Ran "git pull origin master --rebase" to get changes from the team again before pushing

Now, the issue showed up when I do step 5 "git pull origin master --rebase". I'm getting conflicts, and the conflicts are between the code I pushed in step3 and the code I have locally. However, I'm pretty sure that the remote master branch is clean and does not have code from this branch.

I tried the following operations, and only one of them is giving me issue:

- git pull origin master (from master branch) [good]
- git pull origin master (from feature branch) [good]
- git pull origin master --rebase (from master branch) [good]
- git pull origin master --rebase (from feature branch) [not good] <-- containing code from step 3.

Could anyone shed some lights on this, please? Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little unsure what you mean by "Containing code from step 3". Could you clarify with concrete code, perhaps? The chronology is a bit unclear to me - You say you're working with a team.

In step 5, did someone else work on the same regions of the code as you?

Comment: @zrrbite Yes, definitely. So say I had `let a = 'Hello World'` at step 1, and I changed it to `let a = 'Hey Cat'` at step 4. When I tried to do a rebase(step 5), I got a conflict between `let a = 'Hello World'`(upcoming changes) and `let a = 'Hey Cat'`(current changes). I don't think anyone has made any changes to the same regions of code. Hope this helps. Please let me know if you need me to clarify further.

Answer (score 1):

I would replace the pull --rebase by

```
git checkout the-branch-I-want
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
```

That way, I am sure of which branch is rebasing onto what.